# Driving lamps with the fewest number of NPN switch transistors

Tags: transistors, digital-logic, npn, nixie

I'm building a small system to drive some Nixie lamps and I'm missing some of the classic ICs that could make this design significant simpler. I ended up with some discrete NPNs to select the lamp and another line to select the digit.

Is there some other, significantly simpler, way to arrange these transistors to make a better use of them and achive the same? i.e. one 5V open drain for lamp and one 5V open drain for the digit.

[image]

Comment: It is hard to understand your intentions, but IMO the best way is to make a PCB for each lamp with a shift register and discrete transistors, then you interconnect those PCBs together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you control the system with a microcontroller, you can avoid Q3 and Q4 by having one control line per digit. If the UC doesn't have enough output you can use a shift register.
2. You could use Mosfet / BJT arrays like [this one](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/central-semiconductor-corp/MPQ7043-PBFREE/5018754?s=N4IgjCBcoOwCxVAYygMwIYBsDOBTANCAPZQDaIATAAwDMAbDQJwgC6hADgC5QgDKnAJwCWAOwDmIAL6EAHGATQQKSBhwFiZcHCoy4MkITABWGBUYRDMiqZgHKYekaqsO3SH0GiJk6ZU0AjACtuFkkgA) to have fewer components but might be more expensive.

---

Alternatively, you can multiplex the lamps from the high side as follow:

[image: schematic]

- You can multiplex at a frequency that is not visible to the eye (few kHz), although the overall brightness will be lower, you can probably drive the nixie harder as well.
- Select proper Mosfet and use proper protection, especially for the high side. You can also use BJT.

---

Example for high side drive using BJT: (using random components)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fMrVKl.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: There’s been previous questions relating to multiplexing nixies here. I’d suggest you do a search.

Comment: Thanks Damien - great suggestions! Great insights into using the a) shift registers, b) mosfets. Just to ask for a clarification - if using a PNP on the high side, I noticed in the simulation that I would be getting HV (150+) on the base terminal. What kind of protection would be required to allow connecting that to the LV (5V) safely?

Comment: @balaur, yes it's correct, if you use BJT you basically need another BJT to drive it from a microcontroller. I will add the example

Comment: Sounds good, @damien! Thanks!